# phonegap plugin add org.any.plugin seems ok but not added to the project?

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I try to add a plugin via `phonegap plugin add org.apache.cordova.device` in mac terminal, its get some time and say

```
[phonegap] adding the plugin: org.apache.cordova.device
[phonegap] successfully added the plugin
```

but it's not added to iOS project plugin folder.

**Update 1**

also run the command `phonegap build ios`

Thanks
DamithH

Answer (score 0):

Have you built the project by running the command below?

```
phonegap build ios
```

To my understanding, the command-line tools update the project structure at build time, so the plugin will be deployed to the actual ios platform project at that time.

By using the "phonegap add ..." command you should be able to use the plugin right away the next tim eyou build and run your application. So if you can find the plugin within the yourAppFolder/plugins/ folder everything should be fine.

Best.

Comment: So you got it solved? If so, please consider accepting the answer. Otherwise, I'll try to provide some more help. Best.

Comment: No, I run the phonegap build iOS command. after the adding plugin. but it's not added to iOS project plugin folder.

Comment: Can you find it below the yourAppFolder/plugins/ folder?

Comment: Yes. I thing it's come with svn. I get the all phone gap project from svn.

Comment: By the way, by using the "phonegap add ..." command you should be able to use the plugin right away the next tim eyou build and run your application. So if you can find the plugin within the  yourAppFolder/plugins/ folder everything should be fine.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51340/discussion-between-damithh-and-e-valencia)